# Subscribing to Observable returned from a function only works the first time

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I cannot get my function getData to work more than once, the first time getData is called with a field name 'a', the data is returned from returnData and the block inside of getData's .subscribe is hit. The second time getData is called with a field 'b', everything inside of returnData works as expected, however the block inside of getData's .subscribe is not hit at all.

```
private getData(field: string): void { 
  this.returnData(field)                                 
    .subscribe((data) => {
    //Handle Data
    //This block is only hit the first time getData is called
  });}

private returnData(field: string): Observable < SomeObj > {         
  let subj: Subject < SomeObj > = new Subject < SomeObj > ();      
  const obj: SomeObj = new SomeObj(field); 
  this.someDataServive.someFunction(field)
    .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      //set properties on obj from data and emit obj
      subj.next(obj);
      //This block is always hit every time getData is called, and the 
      // obj returned from here is correct
     },                                                            
    (err) => {
      subj.next(obj);
    });                                                             
  return (subj.asObservable());                                        
}
```

Comment: Add typescript to the tags to get syntax highlight, It's already hard to read with all the comments

Comment: I made a plunker with the code for better readability here: https://plnkr.co/edit/pylvkE6QBnqjd81nsWlS?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with my lack of understanding when to .subscribe and when to .map; also Subject was unnecessary. Changing returnData's subscribe to map was all that was needed to consistently hit the .subscribe block in returnData.

```
private returnData(field: string): Observable < SomeObj > {              
  const obj: SomeObj = new SomeObj(field); 
  return this.someDataServive.someFunction(field)
    .map(
    (data) => {
      obj.data = data;
      return obj;
    }                                                                                                    
}
```